# Jquery Tabs Jumping and Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a problem with jquery tabs and It's very similar to the following problem already solved here:

[Click here to see the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762443/page-is-jumping-while-clicking-on-different-2-thumbnail-image)

I did the following, so the jumping while clicking on tabs changed.

But the problem is, the text on my content div differs very much in length and I got an footer in my layout, so if I click the tab with the most text and after that I click the tab with less text, there is a huge gap between text and the footer.
Is there any possibility that the height is always really adjusting exactly to the length of the text and doesn't stay the highest when you clicked a certain tab?

I hope my problem is understandable and I'd really appreciate the help.

Here is my example:

http://crossmediasolutions.de/cmsweb/index.htm

the jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $(".tabs li:first").addClass("current").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    $(".tabs li").click(function() {
        $(".tabs li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $('.tab_container').css('min-height', $('.tab_container').height()+'px');
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us your code/Fiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, could you look at my code again, unfourtunatly I changed it to the correct form just yet. the problem is at the <div class="tab_container">

Comment: Make a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net or bin it at  https://www.jsbin.com , otherwise it's very cumbersome to go to a site and find out the specific problem , since there will also be a lot of data in it .

Comment: Why are you changing min-height of tab_container and not it's actual height?

Comment: If I'm changing the actual height, the content of <div class="tab_container"> if floating over the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tab_container height should be bigger than your active content height.
You should try something like this:

```
$(".tabs li").click(function() {
        $(".tabs li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        var h = $(activeTab).height() + 20;
        $('.tab_container').css('height', h + 'px');
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work but it's still jumping a little bit when I scroll down a bit and click on a new tab

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"? 
Maybe it is because of fadein effect? - Try using $(activeTab).show(); 
You could also play a little bit with the order of the commands in function in may improve the situation...

Comment: Yeah but I think I'm good now. Looks good, thank you very much!